# "public key" and "account" : are the same?

Tags: transactions, accounts, private-key, public-key

When I create a new account as follows :

```
web3.eth.personal.newAccount('pass').then(console.log);

-> pass is account password.
```

Then, I receive an account as follows :

```
0x15CaFbd23DEB631447D34de50e961B0049f4Df2B
```

Is this my `public key` ? And if so, How can I see my `private key` ?

Meanwhile, **sometimes** when I sent a transaction, I need to unlock my account by account password via `ParityUI`. Why do I need to do this only **sometimes** ?

And if I create an account **without password** as follows, what happens ?

```
web3.eth.personal.newAccount().then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I create a new account as follows :
>
> web3.eth.personal.newAccount('pass').then(console.log);
>
> -> pass is account password.
>
> Then, I receive an account as follows :
>
> 0x15CaFbd23DEB631447D34de50e961B0049f4Df2B
>
> Is this my public key ? And if so, How can I see my private key ?

Yes, that is your public key. The private key is saved in a keyfile that is encrypted and can be opened with the password you used to create the account. The private key can be recovered with [keyethereum](https://github.com/ethereumjs/keythereum):

privateKey = keythereum.recover(password, keyObject);

> Meanwhile, sometimes when I sent a transaction, I need to unlock my account by account password via ParityUI. Why do I need to do this
>   only sometimes ?

This is because the account gets unlocked only for a period of time, when this expires, for security, you need to unlock again.

> And if I create an account without password as follows, what happens ?
>   web3.eth.personal.newAccount().then(console.log);

This should produce an error because the password is required to open the keyfile.

Comment: Thank you. Just concerning when I unlock my account using account password: Logically in `Ethereum` and `Bitcoin` we sign our transaction using our `private key`, isn't it ? But in this case we use our `password` similar to [IOTA public ledger](https://github.com/iotaledger) . I'm wrong ? Thanks

Comment: In ethereum you use your private key, but this is transparent to the user. Geth will use your password to access the key file and then use the private key to sign the transaction. You can actually do this manually. Once you get the private key, you can use web3 functions to sign transaction by yourself, if you are curious you can take a  look at the examples [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#signtransaction)

Comment: Thank you. Just I appreciate if you mention related link in which I could find these commands to sign transaction direcly by private key. Btw, I think you mean : "_but this is NOT transparent to the user_", isn't it ? Thanks again

Comment: By transparent I mean you do not have to do it yourself, geth will do it if you unlock your account. The links are in my previous comment at the end where it says "here".